# Automatically delete blank cells when copying column, the initial column contains values derived from FORMULAS

Tags: excel-2007

So I have one column of data created with blanks, this data is the source for a data validation drop down box...THE BLANKS ARE IN MY BOX!!

So to eliminate the drop down box option of 'blank' I am going to copy the data into another column, ignoring blank inputs. Problem is the initial data in the first column has been derived via a formula.

So...I need a way of copying the values in one column into another column, ignoring blanks, whilst the values are formed by a formula.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t understand your requirement (and suspect others don’t either or you would have received an answer before now!) but offer a couple of suggestions:

1. If the validation list need not be dynamic (ie not required to respond to changes in the results of the formulae) then when copying into the blank column, use Paste Special Values, sort and then restrict your data validation list range accordingly. Maybe at the same time take the opportunity to limit the validation list to unique records only.
2. If the validation list needs to be dynamic then don’t copy your ‘first column’ but refer to it instead (say with `=A1` copied down to suit). Then select the new column, Go To Special, Formulas, Text (only), right click on one of the selected cells, Delete…, Shift cells up. Select your validation list range to suit. In this case you may have to accept duplicate values, if these happen to have been derived from different formulae.